# How can I start and stop a for loop with the press of a button in Android Studio?

Tags: android, list, for-loop, android-button

I have made a button on clicking which goes through a list and takes out individual items and sends them via Bluetooth to the hardware.
What I want to do is when I click the button once again it should stop the execution of the loop in between and no more values should be sent.
I have tried making it with a variable, which turns true and false on the clicking and the loop continues only when the variable is true.

Here it is:

```
run.setOnClickListener{
        if (!stop){
            stop = true
            runList()
        }
        else{
            stop = false
        }
    }

 private fun runList() {
    for (i in 0 until order.size) {
        if(stop) {
            //Elements to send come here, using order[i] 
        }
        if (!stop) {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But in this code, the loop just continues till the very end when all the items are completed even if I click the button again in between the execution. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: What I am noticing is that the value of the stop variable is not updated in the if statement in the for loop so it keeps executing until the very end, so how can I do that the value of stop gets updated for the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your logic is confused. Try with this.

```
 run.setOnClickListener{
    if (!stop){
        stop = true
    }else{
        stop = false
    }
    runList();
}

 private fun runList() {
 if(stop){
     for (i in 0 until order.size) {
      //Elements to send come here, using order[i] 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, please help

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?